# Potential for the Haar measure on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider the measure on the complex plane define by $\mu = d d^c \log^+ |z| = \frac{i}{\pi}\partial \bar \partial \log^+ |z|$, where $\log^+ = \max(\log,0)$ and the derivatives are taken in the sense of distributions (or currents).

From the fact that $\log^+$ is zero on $\{|z|<1\}$ and harmonic on $\{|z|>1\}$ we see that the support of $\mu$ is contained in $S^1$ and in fact one can show that it is equal to $S^1$. What I am trying to see is that $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $S^1$.

This measure is clearly invariant under translations, so if its mass is finite it should be a multiple of the Haar measure. My question is: how can we see that the mass is finite and that this multiple is 1?

Comment: Hint: use one of Green's identities for the function $\log^+$ on a larger disk. The boundary integral of normal derivative gives the total mass of Laplacian inside the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an answer here: the required Green's identity is really the divergence theorem applied to the gradient of the function $\log^+$. Since the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient, integration of the flux of the gradient across the boundary captures the total amount of Laplacian in that domain. The function does not need to be smooth for this to work, since the distributional Laplacian is defined via integration by parts to begin with.

In the concrete example here, the flux of the gradient across the circle $|z|=r$ is zero when $r<1$ and $2\pi$ when $r>1$.